# External Javascript Function not updating html div in Backbone JS

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js

I have a js file called Notification.js containing a function to populate a div meant to show messages with the Message I pass to it, as shown below

Notification.js

```
function msgStatus(Message) {
    $("#Messagebar").html(Message);
    $("#Messagebar").css("color","#000000");
}
```

In my backbone js view I am calling this function as follows (of course after pulling the Notification.js in the define section of my view)

```
render: function () {
  this.$el.html(this.template_catalog());
  msgStatus("This is a test message");
  return this;
}
```

But the div is not getting populated with the message. It remains blank.
Can you please let me know where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The view is propobly not appended to the DOM yet, so when you call `msgStatus("This is a test message");` the `$("#Messagebar")` is undefined.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Is there a way I can know when the view is appended to the DOM?